# php- extra comma appears while converting an array to csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an array which looks somewhat like this

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Name","Price","Hours"),
  array("AMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Cand Rover",17,15)
  );
```

And I'm trying to convert this array to CSV data so that I can write it into a file.

I have a function which takes an array as input and converts it into CSV format. It looks like this:

```
function array_2_csv($array) 
{
     $csv = array();
     foreach ($array as $item) 
     {
         if (is_array($item)) 
         {
             $csv[] = array_2_csv($item);
             $csv[]="\r\n";
         } 
         else 
         {
             $csv[] = $item;
         }
     }
     return implode(',', $csv);
}
```

It works but an extra comma appears on front of lines. How can I remove that?

**Expected Output**

```
Name,Price,Hours
AMW,15,13,
Saab,5,2,
Cand Rover,17,15
```

**Output I'm getting is**:

```
Name,Price,Hours,
,AMW,15,13,
,Saab,5,2,
,Cand Rover,17,15,
```

**Full Code**

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Name","Price","Hours"),
  array("AMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Cand Rover",17,15)
  );
$csv_data = array_2_csv($cars);

echo $csv_data;
function array_2_csv($array) 
{
     $csv = array();
     foreach ($array as $item) 
     {
         if (is_array($item)) 
         {
             $csv[] = array_2_csv($item);
             $csv[]="\r\n";
         } 
         else 
         {
             $csv[] = $item;
         }
     }
     return implode(',', $csv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below (your code modification):-

```
$csv_data = array_2_csv($cars);

echo $csv_data;
function array_2_csv($array) 
{
     $csv = ''; //take string
     foreach ($array as $item) 
     {
         if (is_array($item)) 
         {
             $csv .= implode(',',$item); // implode and add to string
             $csv .="\r\n"; // add new line
         }else{
           $csv .= $item; // direct add value to string
           $csv .="\r\n"; //add new line
         } 

     }
     return $csv; //return string
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/752820

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be writing the contents to a file anyway then why not cut out the middleman and just use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

This way you function would look something like:

```
function array_2_csv($array, $fileName)
{
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    foreach ($array as $fields) {
        fputcsv($file, $fields);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Then your call would be something like:

```
array_2_csv($cars, 'path-to-file')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do more functional style and use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with couple of [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions:

```
function array_2_csv(array $array, $delimiter = ',') 
{
    return implode('', array_map(function ($item) use ($delimiter) {
        return implode($delimiter, $item) . PHP_EOL;
    }, $array));
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95ccd92e82e37cb5074a87d2234386758fb3e0c6).

But if you want just write the results to file then [@RossWilson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733554/4355258) is better. As [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) can properly escape quotes and also can take the `$delimeter` option and `$escape_char` option.

And as for why you are getting so many commas in your own code. Firstly, you implode some things twice. Secondly, you are adding the end of line symbol before imploding, so the symbol gets implode with the comma too.